# pagenumber in table of contents not correct

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

The pagenumbers of the "part" appendix isn't consistent: in the table of contents is another number than on the page itself. I know thats because of the change from arabic and roman numbering, but I thats what I need. It would be awesome if somebody could help me.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Einstellung der Eingabekodierung
\usepackage[inner=25mm,outer=35mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,]{geometry}          
\usepackage{emptypage}      % Keine Seitenzahlen auf Leerzeiten
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % Anpassung von Kopf- und Fußzeilen

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
% titlepage
% abstract
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
% ...

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{xy}
\chapter{xyz}
% ...

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{8} % Fortsetzung der Seitenzahl 

\appendix

\part*{Anhänge}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Anhänge}

\chapter{Quelltexte}
\chapter{Messwerte}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\part*{Anhänge\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Anhänge}}`, otherwise you are on another page by the time `\addcontentsline` is executed.